# Python module pull_bot_pass

Tags: python, module

i'm trying to code just a basic bot for Discord using python.
One of the modules i have to import is called pull_bot_pass but it tells me the module is missing. Does anyone know where i get the module? IE: Link to download.

Import Code:

```
import pull_bot_pass
```

What it relates to:

```
password = pull_bot_pass.pull_pass()
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the password that he's importing from another python script so that he doesn't have to show it in the video. Just use your own password.
E.g.

```
password = '1499'
```